# How To Debug HTTP Error 400 in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have the following code that prints some links on the page, and is supposed to call a controller method (launch), upon clicking the image.  However, I am getting an Error 400 when I click the button.  The generated links look correct to me.  The code is in the 1st block.  The actual View-Source is in the 2nd.

Unfortunately, I am not getting any errors in my server logs, so I don't know where to begin to debug this.

Does anyone see anything wrong with my code.

```
<div id="links">
    <ul>
        <c:forEach items="${listAppURLForm}" var="appURLForm">
            <li>
                <h2>${appURLForm.link}</h2>
                <p>
                    <span>
                        <form method="post" action='<c:url value="launch"/>'>
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${appURLForm.link}"/>
                            <input type="image" src='<c:url value="/images/rocket-thumbnail.png"/>'/>
                        </form>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The rendered page:

```
<form method="post" action='launch;jsessionid=40d63cd386e5d01ef8c6dc1c1b76'>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="http://www.cnn.com"/>
    <input type="image" src='/services/images/rocket-thumbnail.png;jsessionid=40d63cd386e5d01ef8c6dc1c1b76'/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

400 means server cant understand what browser sent

your action='launch;jsessionid=40d63cd386e5d01ef8c6dc1c1b76' might be ?launch;jsessionid=40d63cd386e5d01ef8c6dc1c1b76

```
    <form method="post" action='?launch;jsessionid=40d63cd386e5d01ef8c6dc1c1b76'>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="http://www.cnn.com"/>
        <input type="image" src='/services/images/rocket-thumbnail.png;jsessionid=40d63cd386e5d01ef8c6dc1c1b76'/>
     </form>
```

Comment: That is supposed to be intercepted by a Spring controller mapped to the URL launch.  I am using another app that does it that way as an example.  It does look funny, though.